# Database has disappeared in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2013

I had a database and now it's not appearing in Visual studio. When I go to the folder I can see files [image]

In visual studio it's not appearing

[image]

Any help really appreciated

Comment: Is it attached in SSMS?

Comment: I don't have SQL sever on my computer

Comment: Just because you can see a file, doesnt mean that its attached to a database instance.  You need to make sure that a SQL server instance points to it, this would be localhost in your case, and that you have set up a connection to it in VS (which looks like what you've done)  Is this the first time you're trying to access this db?